# Can you explain this nested conditional expression?

Tags: perl, conditional-operator

I can't decipher this line of code. Could someone please translate it into `if` / `else` statements?

I understand the basic `CONDITION ? VALUE_IF_TRUE : VALUE_IF_FALSE` pattern, but this line seems to break that.

```
$type = $self->{1}{_flag} & 2 ?
    $self->{2}{_flag} & 2 ? "A" : "B" :
    $self->{2}{_flag} & 2 ? "B" : "C";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of line breaks makes all the difference, although I've also added some parens to make it crystal clear.

```
$type = $self->{1}{_flag} & 2
   ? ( $self->{2}{_flag} & 2 ? "A" : "B" )
   : ( $self->{2}{_flag} & 2 ? "B" : "C" );
```

Comment: So correct me if I'm wrong, Case "C" is when {1}{_flag} is not & 2 and {2}{_flag} is not & 2?

Answer (score 6):

I think it's irresponsible to write code like that where the operator precedence is far from obvious

Using a mixture of `if` / `else` and conditional expressions it looks much clearer like this

```
if ( $self->{1}{_flag} & 2 ) {

    $type = $self->{2}{_flag} & 2 ? "A" : "B";
}
else {

    $type = $self->{2}{_flag} & 2 ? "B" : "C";
}
```

Comment: Ternary operator precedence is obvious enough [unless you use PHP](http://phpsadness.com/sad/30)

Answer (score -1):

That's almost as cryptic as the equivalent

```
$type = (qw/C x B x A/)[ $self->{1}{_flag} & 2 + $self->{2}{_flag} & 2 ];
```

More seriously, nesting ternary operators in the true-branch is confusing.  I'd use an explicit if/else.  Or if I really wanted a ternary, I'd rearrange this to:

```
$type = $self->{1}{_flag} & 2 != $self->{2}{_flag} & 2
    ? 'B'
    : $self->{1}{_flag} & 2
        ? 'A'
        : 'C';
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an actual answer to the question.  I doubt that a Perl user at this level of skill would understand your (admittedly) cryptic equivalent at all.

Comment: Please add explanations to your answer.